# QGIS 3.18.2 Print Composer/Layout map legend vanishes/goes blank when layer/theme is changed

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, qgis-print-layouts

Using the print composer/layout in QGIS 3.18.2 I have the following problem ...

**Starting point:**
I had a print layout set up with a map and legend. The map layers were set by 4 themes. The layout used an atlas. I printed all those maps as expected.

**Now:**
I have made a new theme. When I set that theme in the "Follow map theme" option, the display of the Legend on the page vanishes/goes blank (it is still there as an object and the item properties are editable in the panel ... and I have tried clicking on/off many of the settings to try alter its behaviour, to no avail).

The same thing happens when I change the layers in one of the themes that had worked/printed correctly with a legend functioning properly.

If I uncheck "Follow map theme" on the main map the blank legend problem persists.

If I change the theme back to the original, the legend functions as expected.
If I create a new legend, I can use the new theme ... but now I have recreated the styles 3 times and that is getting a little old and tiring for every time I change a layer/theme! ha

**Help!**
Has anyone encountered this and/or know how to fix this issue/know what might be causing it in my project?

*Legend settings:*
[image]

**Update:**
Unfortunately the problem has occurred in a layout in a completely different project. Perhaps the problem is with my QGIS program and not the layers or layout itself?

Comment: Please add screenshots of you legend settings.

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks for your interest ... which part of the settings? "Auto update" is off, "Only show items inside linked map" is on, "Only show items inside current atlas feature" is off. Also, in the "Main Properties" section up the top, the  legend is properly linked to "Map 1", the only map.

Comment: The top part, where the legend elements are set.

Comment: On the themes you use, do you have all your layers shown in your legend ? Your themes activate different layers or your themes activate different styles on the same layer ?

Comment: Hey thanks Corentin Lemaitre. All my layers are shown in the legend of the main QGIS window, as well as in the "Legend Items" panel within the Layout Composer window. My themes do activate (turn on/off) different layer combinations but my themes don't activate different styles on any of the layers used. The completely blank legend is for all the layers, including things like roads and streams that I have used in countless projects. Everything else looks normal.